# Horizontal slider plugin for react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, package

What is the best horizontal slider plugin for react-native?
I found some but not working well.

Comment: You can use `ScrollView` or `FlatList` with `horizontal` prop you can also set `pagingEnabled ` to true to make scroll per each full slide

Answer (score 0):

I've used two: react-navigation or react-native-swiper.

The first is about navigate into screen, and the second is better to make an onboarding page.

Regards,